# Error while changing the authentication - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I had database level authentication in mongoDB, I had tried to change the password for existing user. It is throwing `not authorized` error.

#### Steps i followed to change the password

```
use wallet
db.auth("username","password")
db.changeUserPassword("username","newpassword");
```

#### Error

Changing password failed: not authorized for update on wallet.system.users at src/mongo/shell/db.js:186

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: You do not have permission to change user information (such as password).

Comment: Does the user you're logged in with has the 'userAdmin' or 'userAdminAnyDatabase' role?
If not, your user cannot alter other users information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to login and use ADMIN database to perform the operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have changed security settings in `Mongo` configuration file you would not be able to change the password. To do so, set `authorization` to `disabled`:

Stop `mongod` service:

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
```

Open `Mongo` configuration file (paths may be different on your system):

**Linux**

> Config file path: "/etc/mongod.conf"

**Windows**

> Config file path: "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\mongod.cfg"

Find `authorization` and set it to `disabled`:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

change to:

```
security:
  authorization: disabled
```

Now start `Mongo` service:

```
$ sudo service mongod start
```

and change password from within `Mongo` shell:

```
> use mydb
> db.updateUser("myUser", {pwd: "myNewPassword" })
```

Now you can set `authorization` back to what it was. Just stop `Mongo` service, change settings and start service.